# Where did the # (hash, number sign) notation for hexadecimal RGB colour triples originate?

Tags: history, graphics, internet

The hexadecimal notation `#RRGGBB` for RGB colour triples has been popularised by HTML and is commonly associated with it, even though nowadays it is not usually used in HTML directly, but rather through CSS.

I noticed that the same notation is used in the X pixmap format (XPM), which to my knowledge was created in 1989, thus predating HTML (1993).

Where does this notation come from? How did it end up in HTML?

Comment: This probably has no "answer" in the accepted definition on stack exchange and this site as the notation is the natural one in a world where programmer's commonly deal with machine representations of numbers.  Hexadecimal notation was common at that time (as it still is).  If there had been color displays a decade earlier RGB notation might have been written in octal - that would have been natural for 666 color on 18-bit or 36 bit machines ... but they still would have switched to hex notation for color when the whole industry went that way ...

Comment: @davidbak: Oh come on. The [question about `$`](/q/15899) and [about `0x`](/q/15897) managed to be answered. (I can’t speak as for the *correctness* of the answer, but…)

Comment: After glancing at early HTML specifications, I believe that coloring was introduced (i.e., specified; it might have been implemented earlier) only by [HTML 3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/), in 1997. Previous versions don't say anything about color, and `#` is used solely for IDs and entity references. The HTML 3.2 specification mentions that the the 16 "standard" colors were derived from the Windows VGA palette; that might be a lead.

Comment: If I'm wrong, I'm wrong.  That's fine.  And that's why I commented, not answered.  @texdr.aft - Windows did use that notation as early as 2.0, probably in 1.0 though I don't know.

Comment: @davidbak Good to know. It seems likely that it comes from a convention for hexadecimal numbers in general. [Wikipedia, without citing any sources, agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#Computing) and says that the exact origin was X11 (or an early version thereof) color notation, which was in turn inspired by some assemblers. So far I haven't been able to find any old X windows documentation to verify the claim.

Comment: [This historical archive of early versions of X's `rgb.txt`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~alanc/xc-historical/log/xc/programs/rgb/rgb.txt) does not have colors in hexadecimal; I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @texdr.aft however the X11R3 manuals describe RGB colour triplets in #-prefixed hex notation, with up to four hex digits per component.

Comment: @StephenKitt As does the X11R1 documentation (apparently from 1987). But it doesn't seem to mention the origin of the notation.

Comment: @texdr.aft yup, it’s a shame documentation authors never seem to predict and address Retro.SE questions ;-).

Comment: @texdr.aft not in colors.txt but the X man page has it: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~alanc/xc-historical/tree/xc/doc/man/general/X.man?id=8ff23fe979c40b2ed98373b43986484f6b045f0d has it and says it it's older.

Comment: @Jasen - I don't see where that doc says it's older, could you point it out please?   (It probably doesn't help that I'm reading the raw markup, not the formatted page).

Comment: you're right, it doesn't say that it's older, ony the current documentation says that. (preferring rgb:XXXXXX or rgba:XXXXXXXX instead)

Answer (score 17):

HTML colours came from X11, being slightly altered first.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names

The #RGB and #RRGGBB syntax used by WWW was previously present in X11 too.

This 1988 [commit tp the X(7) man page](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/%7Ealanc/xc-historical/commit/xc/doc/man/general/X.man?id=58790799c9ce9f7824ea8a2603f67b12c6e28396) describes it (see the section "color names")

`xsetroot` ( historical version ) calls `XParseColor()`, and while the current man page for `XParseColor()` lists #RRGGBB as an allowed format, I was unable to find the corresponding man page on the Xorg site, though the content seems similar to the X(7) page above.

Interestingly, the current man page for `XParseColor` says that #RGB is scaled to #R0G0B0 rather than #RRGGBB, so #FFF is the same as #F0F0F0 under X11 rather than #FFFFFF (like it is for WWW). This is another departure from X11.

Comment: Would be good to also include how did it happen that X11 syntax ended up in HTML (as far as I can find, HTML colours were a Netscape invention, and Netscape was primarily an X client, so my guess is that this is where it specifically came from), and where X11 itself took it from (this one might be harder).

Comment: I can't say sure sure if it was netscape or mosaic.

Comment: Interesting that it specifies zero-extension like that - I would consider that a specification error.  (I once wrote some code that had to extend 5 bit-per-channel images up to 8 bit-per-channel and made absolutely sure that `1F` multiplied up to become `FF`...).

Comment: Yeah, that is an oddity. perhaps that why it is now deprecated in X11, `rgb:fff` , the new form, expands to `rgb:ffffffffffff`.  I tested `#FFF` and it does indeed expand to `#F0F0F0`

Comment: @TobySpeight Something like (x<<3)|(x>>2)  ?

Comment: @LeoB., yes, something like that (somewhat different because three channels were packed into two 8-bit bytes).

Comment: Mosaic - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_(web_browser) - was originally written for X11 on Unix (PC's were not powerful enough yet).  Mosaic was the base for Netscape which essentially defined the initial world wide web, so I agree that the X11 notation is a very good guess.